# Select certain region of column for lm

Tags: r

I am trying to build several linear regression models from a data frame with two columns, one of which should only contain a certain part of the column. My data (let's say it's called df) kinda looks like this:

```
Year percentage_hesc_EU
2018 0,02
2017 0,03
2016 2,1
2015 0,4
2014 0,2
. 
.
.
1998 0,1
```

Now I have one regression that is supposed to go from 2018 to 2011 and one that is supposed to go from 2010 to 1998

So far, I have done the following:

```
EU_hesc_Pre_BvG <- lm(percentage_hesc_EU ~ Year, data = df[df$Year <=2010,])
EU_hesc_Post_BvG <- lm(percentage_hesc_EU ~ Year, data = df[df$Year > 2010,])
```

That gave me two of the regressions I need. But now I want to make one that goes from 2007 to 2010 but I don't know how to model this. I tried:

```
EU_hesc_Pre_BvG <- lm(percentage_hesc_EU ~ Year, data = df[df$Year 2010:2007,])
```

and:

```
EU_hesc_Pre_BvG <- lm(percentage_hesc_EU ~ Year, data = df[df$Year 2007:2010,])
```

but neither worked. Im kinda new to R, but I am very thankful for your guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either of the following two:

```
df[df$Year >= 2007 & df$Year <= 2010,]
df %>% dplyr::filter(Year >= 2007, Year <= 2010)
```